# How can I enable all NvChad features?

Tags: neovim, lua, nvchad, plugin-nvimtree

I am struggling to enable the features advertised on https://nvchad.netlify.app/features. Upon installation, we only get basic features such as tabs and command bar, as per my experience and what I see from the tutorials. I tried using require in the init.lua but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my init.lua after the install process from the docs:

```
vim.defer_fn(function()
  pcall(require, "impatient")
end, 0)

require "core"
require "core.options"

-- setup packer + plugins
local fn = vim.fn
local install_path = fn.stdpath "data" .. "/site/pack/packer/opt/packer.nvim"

if fn.empty(fn.glob(install_path)) > 0 then
  vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "NormalFloat", { bg = "#1e222a" })
  print "Cloning packer .."
  fn.system { "git", "clone", "--depth", "1", "https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim", install_path }

  -- install plugins + compile their configs
  vim.cmd "packadd packer.nvim"
  require "plugins"
  vim.cmd "PackerSync"

  -- install binaries from mason.nvim & tsparsers
  vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("User", {
    pattern = "PackerComplete",
    callback = function()
      vim.cmd "bw | silent! MasonInstallAll" -- close packer window
      require("packer").loader "nvim-treesitter"
    end,
  })
end

pcall(require, "custom")

require("core.utils").load_mappings()
```

Comment: Did you follow the [installation](https://nvchad.netlify.app/getting-started/setup) steps? What is not working? Could give us your input,, the current behavior and the expected behavior. It will help to understand what is not working and where you are blocked?

Comment: Yes I followed the installation process. It's my first time using neovim so unsure what I should have expected but I seem to miss all the features like for example the nvim-tree

Comment: my experience was like in this video: https://youtu.be/ETIUU9wxmK0

Comment: Nice video:-) what I mean is could you tell us what you type in Neovim, what you get (a screen shot may help) and what you would like to get (a anoted picture could help) :-)

Comment: I'm sorry to insist but without list your  actions and resulting screenshots we have no way to know what goes wrong :-/ and it is very difficult to help you.

Comment: What is the content of you `~\AppData\Local\nvim` folder? Do you have only `init.lua` or both `init.vim` and `init.lua`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK so I was basically trying to setup dashboard-vim and nvim-tree to maybe show on launch and other common things. Apparently there's no preset from NVChad.

Comment: If you want to clarify your question the best is to edit your question. The answer are supposed to be answers ;-)

Comment: *perhaps* this is answering the question by saying “these are not features of NvChad, so I did nothing wrong but my expectations were wrong”? If that’s the case, an [edit] to be more explicit would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

NvChad rely on `~\AppData\Local\nvim\init.lua` in particular you can't have a `init.vim` in the `~\AppData\Local\nvim` folder.

To install NvChad you have to replace the full content of `~\AppData\Local\nvim` by the `VvChad` content (in particular the `init.lua` and the `lua` folder)

To toggle `NvimTree` you have to use the `:NvimTreeToggle` command or with the NvChad shortcut <kbd>Ctrl-n</kbd>:

[image]

To display the dashboard the command should be `:Alpha` but I fail to make it working on my machine (maybe you have the same problem).

Comment: it says 'not an editor command :Alpha'

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm not sure it is working on Windows. I noticed the it depend on base64 that fail to load because of local problems (run `:checkhealth` to see the problem) if I define `LC_ALL` I can solve the `checkhealth` and the installation of `alpha` but it is still not working. I'm stuck too :-)